# What runs before main()?

Tags: c++

After testing on msvc8, I found:

1. Parse GetCommandLine() to argc and argv
2. Standard C Library initialization
3. C++ Constructor of global variables

These three things are called before entering main().

My questions are:

1. Will this execution order be different when I porting my program to different compiler (gcc or armcc), or different platform?
2. What stuff does Standard C Library initialization do? So far I know setlocale() is a must.
3. Is it safe to call standard C functions inside C++ constructor of global variables?

Comment: what are you trying to do?  the library initialzation also create a few buffer for some functions (e.g. buffer for iostream). There are too many miscellaneous tasks to list.

Comment: What runs before main?  Whatever it's chasing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1: Will this execution order be different when I porting my program to different compiler (gcc or armcc), or different platform?

Yes.

> 2: What stuff does Standard C Library initialization do? So far I know setlocale() is a must.

I am sure there is other stuff. You should not rely on any global objects util after main has started. This means things like std streams (std::cin, std::cout) may not be usable.

> 3: Is it safe to call standard C functions inside C++ constructor of global variables?

Probably not.

Comment: @ephemient: Probably safe. But probably not a good idea. These streams use the locale another global variable but its value may or may not be the current locale or "C". The unspecified order is not a real problem (if you know it exists (Its just an annoyance that can be worked around (it is a problem if you don;t know it exists))).

Answer (score 5):

Here's an [article](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib---libc-start-main-.html) from the LSB (Linux Standard Base) effort describing what `__libc_start_main` might do on Linux.

Specifically:

> ```
> * performing any necessary security checks if the effective user
>   ID is not the same as the real user ID.
> * initialize the threading subsystem.
> * registering the rtld_fini to release resources when this dynamic
>   shared object exits (or is unloaded).
> * registering the fini handler to run at program exit.
> * calling the initializer function (*init)().
> * calling main() with appropriate arguments.
> * calling exit() with the return value from main().
> ```

And here's a [more detailed explanation](http://linuxgazette.net/84/hawk.html).

This is definitely different to Windows.

Comment: And that's not even getting into what the C++ runtime library does!

Comment: Being a C++ user hurts my head enough, without trying to look at an implementation of the C++ runtime library...