# Why does GCC delete my code on O3 but not on O0?

Tags: c++

Recently i have been trying to learn about rvalues and perfect forwarding. While playing around with some constructs i came across some peculiar behavior while switching compilers and optimization levels.

Compiling the same code on GCC with no optimization turned on would yield expected results, however turning on any optimization level then would result all of my code being deleted.
Compiling the same code on clang with no optimizations also yields expected results. Then turning on optimizations on clang would still yield expected results.

I know this screams undefined behavior but i just cannot figure out what exactly is going wrong and whats causing the discrepancy between the two compilers.

```
gcc -O0 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5xY1Gz

```
gcc -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra
```

https://godbolt.org/z/fE3TE5

```
clang -O0 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra
```

https://godbolt.org/z/W98fh8

```
clang -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6sEo8j

```
#include <utility>

// lambda_t is the type of thing we want to call.
// capture_t is the type of a helper object that 
// contains all all parameters meant to be passed to the callable
template< class lambda_t, class capture_t >
struct CallObject {

    lambda_t  m_lambda;
    capture_t m_args;

    typedef decltype( m_args(m_lambda) ) return_t;

    //Construct the CallObject by perfect forwarding which is
    //neccessary as they may these are lambda which will have
    //captured objects and we dont want uneccessary copies
    //while passing these around
    CallObject( lambda_t&& p_lambda, capture_t&& p_args ) :
        m_lambda{ std::forward<lambda_t>(p_lambda) },
        m_args  { std::forward<capture_t>(p_args) }
    {

    }

    //Applies the arguments captured in m_args to the thing
    //we actually want to call
    return_t invoke() {
        return m_args(m_lambda);
    }

    //Deleting special members for testing purposes
    CallObject() = delete;
    CallObject( const CallObject& ) = delete;
    CallObject( CallObject&& ) = delete;
    CallObject& operator=( const CallObject& ) = delete;
    CallObject& operator=( CallObject&& ) = delete;
};

//Factory helper function that is needed to create a helper
//object that contains all the paremeters required for the 
//callable. Aswell as for helping to properly templatize
//the CallObject
template< class lambda_t, class ... Tn >
auto Factory( lambda_t&& p_lambda, Tn&& ... p_argn ){

    //Using a lambda as helper object to contain all the required paramters for the callable
    //This conviently allows for storing value, references and so on
    auto x = [&p_argn...]( lambda_t& pp_lambda ) mutable -> decltype(auto) {

        return pp_lambda( std::forward<decltype(p_argn)>(p_argn) ... );
    };

    typedef decltype(x) xt;
    //explicit templetization is not needed in this case but
    //for the sake of readability it needed here since we then
    //need to forward the lambda that captures the arguments
    return CallObject< lambda_t, xt >( std::forward<lambda_t>(p_lambda), std::forward<xt>(x) );
}

int main(){

    auto xx = Factory( []( int a, int b ){

        return a+b;

    }, 10, 3 );

    int q = xx.invoke();

    return q;
}
```

Comment: `I know this screams undefined behavior but i just cannot figure out what exactly is going wrong` You said what's going wrong in that sentence. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: But why? I want to understand what what I've done wrong. Its not giving me warnings even with -Wall -Wextra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does GCC delete my code on O3

Because GCC is very smart, figures out that your program doesn't depend on any runtime input, and thus optimises it to constant output at compile time.

> just cannot figure out what exactly is going wrong and whats causing the discrepancy between the two compilers.

The behaviour of the program is undefined. There is no reason to expect there to not be discrepancy between compilers, or any particular behaviour.

> > The behaviour of the program is undefined.
>
> But why?

Here:

> ```
> auto xx = Factory(the_lambda, 10, 3);
> ```

You pass literals to the function, which are prvalues.

> ```
> auto Factory( lambda_t&& p_lambda, Tn&& ... p_argn )
> ```

The function accepts them by reference. Therefore temporary objects are created, whose lifetime extends until the end of the full expression (which is longer than lifetime of the argument references, so the lifetime of the temporaries are not extended).

> ```
> auto x = [&p_argn...]( //...
> ```

The referred temporaries are stored in a lambda... by reference. At no point is there an integer stored in a lambda.

When you later call the lambda, those temporary objects that were referred no longer exist. Those non-existing objects are accessed outside their lifetime, and the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

Mistakes like this are the reason why `std::thread`, `std::bind` and similar which bind arguments always store a value rather than a reference.

Answer (score 5):

If something like this happens, it's ususally because you have undefined behavior somewhere in your program. The compiler did detect this and when optimizing aggressively will throw away your entire program as a result.

In your concrete example, you already get a hint that something is not quite right in the form of a compiler warning:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:45:18: warning: '<anonymous>' is used uninitialized [-Wuninitialized]
   45 |         return a+b;
      |                  ^
```

How could this happen? What could lead to `b` being uninitialized at this point?

Since `b` is a function parameter at this point, the problem must lie with the *caller* of that lambda. Examining the call site we notice something fishy:

```
auto x = [&p_argn...]( lambda_t& pp_lambda ) mutable -> decltype(auto) {
    return pp_lambda( std::forward<decltype(p_argn)>(p_argn) ... );
};
```

The argument bound to `b` is passed as a parameter pack `p_argn`. But notice the lifetime of that parameter pack: It's captured by reference! So there is no perfect forwarding going on here, despite the fact that you wrote `std::forward` in the lambda body, because you capture by reference in the lambda, and the lambda does not "see" what happens outside its body in the surrounding function. You get the same lifetime problem with `a` here too, but for some reason, the compiler chooses not to complain about that one. That's undefined behavior for you, there's no guarantee you'll get a warning for it. The quickest way to fix this is to just capture the arguments by value. You can retain the perfect forwarding property by using a named capture, with the somewhat peculiar syntax:

```
auto x = [...p_argn = std::forward<decltype(p_argn)>(p_argn)]( lambda_t& pp_lambda ) mutable -> decltype(auto) {
    return pp_lambda(std::move(p_argn)... );
};
```

Be sure you understand what is actually being stored where in this case, maybe even draw a picture. It is vital to be able to know exactly where the individual objects live when writing code like this, otherwise it's very easy to write lifetime bugs like this.

Answer (score 1):

> ...  would yield **expected** results, however turning on any optimization level then would result all of my code being deleted.

The question is:

What exactly do you expect?

Most people do not expect a program to contain certain assembler code; most people only expect executable programs (under Windows this would be the `.exe` file) to have a certain "black-box" behaviour:

The program should print a certain text to the console, write to certain files, display certain windows in the GUI, print certain text on the printer, create certain network connections and so on.

The only "black-box" behaviour your program has is that it returns the exit code 0.

This means that the best compiler optimization possible throws away everything which is not needed to return 0 as `exit()` code.

... and this means that the following code remains on 32- and 64-bit x86 systems:

```
xor eax, eax
ret
```

And exactly this is what was done [in the link you provided](https://godbolt.org/z/fE3TE5).

(**EDIT**)

Sorry, but I didn't read the following part of your question:

> I know this screams undefined behavior ...

In this case this means:

The program **not** being optimized (`-O0`) will return different values depending on the data being in the RAM before your program is started.

Depending on the OS you use this may be depending on the program that was running before your program.

Obviously the "black-box" behaviour of your (un-optimized) program may either be returning 0 or 13 as `exit()` code depending on the content of the RAM before starting the program.

Therefore the "best possible" compiler optimization may either simply return 0 or 13 as `exit()` code assuming that the RAM contains certain data before starting your program.

You might argue: *"But my OS will set the RAM content to a certain value (e.g. 0) before the program is started."*

However, even in this case the `exit()` code still depends on the way how the (non-optimizing) compiler *exactly* translates the program.

Answer (score 0):

You got some big hints from the compiler:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:45:18: warning: '<anonymous>' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

   45 |         return a+b;

      |                  ^

<source>:45:18: warning: '<anonymous>' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

ASM generation compiler returned: 0
```

The issue is that you capture your argument list (10, 3) by reference, but those are temporary values when captured.  If you either capture by value or pass actual variables, the code compiles without errors and I get the expected result.

The reason all your code is "deleted" is because gcc and clang are both smart enough to realize you're asking it to add two numbers together, so they've optimized almost your entire program away.  The finally assembly looks like this:

```
main:
        mov     eax, 13
        ret
```